# Quake BSPs in pyopengl

Tags: python, bsp, quake

I can’t find anything about a BSP loader in pyopengl. I want to make a quake like game/engine in python for a class but I can only find stuff on OBJs and nothing on Quake BSPs. If it comes to it I will convert use BSP2OBJ

I have not tried any but I can not find documentation on BSPs in pyopengl